# Having trouble conditionally moving files based on their names

Tags: matlab, acoustics

I am trying to write a script that will auto sort files based on the 7th and 8th digit in their name. I get the following error: `"Argument must be a string scalar or character vector"`. Error is coming from line 16:

> Argument must be a string scalar or character vector.
>
> Error in sort_files (line 16)
>       movefile (filelist(i), DirOut)

Here's the code:

```
DirIn = 'C:\Folder\Experiment' %set incoming directory
DirOut = 'C:\Folder\Experiment\1'

eval(['filelist=dir(''' DirIn '/*.wav'')']) %get file list


for i = 1:length(filelist);
    Filename = filelist(i).name
    name = strsplit(Filename, '_');
    newStr = extractBetween(name,7,8);


    if strcmp(newStr,'01')
       movefile (filelist(i), DirOut)
    end

end
```

Also, I am trying to make the file folder conditional so that if the 10-11 digits are 02 the file goes to DirOut/02 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try avoid using the `eval` function, it is pretty much dreaded as slow and hard to understand. Specially if you need to create variables. Instead do this:

```
filelist = dir(fullfile(DirIn,'*.wav'));
```

Second, the passage:

```
 name = strsplit(Filename, '_');
```

Makes `name` a *list*, so you can access `name{1}` or possibly `name{2}`. Each of these are strings. But `name` isn't a string, it is a list. `extractBetween` requires a string as an input. That is why you are getting this problem. But note that you could have simply done:

```
newStr = name(7:8);
```

If name was a string, which in Matlab is a `char` array.

**EDIT:**

Since it has been now claimed that the error occurs on `movefile (filelist(i), DirOut)`, the likely cause is because `filelist(i)` is a struct. Wheres a filena name (char array) should have been given at input. The solution should be replacing this line with:

```
movefile(fullfile(filelist(i).folder, filelist(i).name), DirOut)
```

Now, if you want to number the output folders too, you can do this:
    movefile(fullfile(filelist(i).folder, filelist(i).name), [DirOut,filesep,name(7:8)])

This will move a file to /DirOut/01. If you wanted /DirOut/1, you could do this:

```
movefile(fullfile(filelist(i).folder, filelist(i).name), [DirOut,filesep,int2str(str2num(name(7:8)))])
```

Comment: @brc: Edited again, please edit your question too, so this detail is in the question and not only in a comment.

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error:

"Index exceeds the number of array elements (1)."